# Identify referrer based on landing URL

Tags: php

I have noticed that when you click on a Google Ads link, it appends this `?gclid=abcdef` on url.
Same behavior goes for facebook as well.

I am using the following block of code in order to identify the referrer.

```
if (strpos($url, 'gclid') !== false) {
    $ref = 'Google Adwords';
} else if  (strpos($url, 'fbclid') !== false) {
    $ref = 'Facebook';
}
```

Is there any other url identifiers or an other way to get the referrer url? The  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` does not work.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` doesn't work because the link to the landing page is in an iframe. That's why the code is in the URL.

Comment: @Barmar, the code is not in an iframe. I don't really understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: That's the way most ads work. There's an iframe that contains the ad media, so that the advertiser can't interfere with the main page. `HTTP_REFERER` contains the URL of the advertiser, not the URL of the main page.

Comment: Right-click on the ad and select Inspect to see how it's embedded in your page.